# The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, provisioning

I am attempting to submit my game to the App Store.  For some reason I am getting this error message when I validate my archive and I have no idea why!

> The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value

The bundle ID in my XCode project directly matches that of the product in iTunes.

Why on earth is submitting to the App Store so complicated.  I've done it three times now and always run into a million problems :/

I have:

- An app created in ITC with the correct bundle identifier
- A company certificate that I use for all my games / apps
- An app ID that directly matches the bundles in both XCode and ITC
- A production provisioning profile that matches the correct bundle ID

Comment: Please check this link https://discussions.apple.com/message/23508889#23508889

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same exact problem, plus it keeps complaining that there's an icon file missing for iPad that is clearly there, added to the plist AND in the Target's General/App icons area. I think Apple just makes things more difficult to try to slow developers down. Android is such a treat compared to this mess! I'll write back if I can figure it out.

EDIT: Holy cow after rebuilding the project from scratch and recreating the provisioning profile I finally noticed that my stinking app in ITC was not set to "Waiting for upload"... dumb on my part, but wow iOS, thanks for picking another app's bundle ID to give me the error instead of telling em what the real problem was!

Comment: I find some of their errors so misleading or downright unhelpful :/